# Any techniques / tools for simulating server and/or network unresponsiveness and network timeouts etc.?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have network handling code in my app (using NSURLConnection/NSURLRequest) and I would like to test how its behaving when the timeout for the connection expires before its received a response.

Any there any techniques/tools for simulating this on the simulator and device?

(NSURLRequest apparently does not allow a very short time out to be set, i.e. one second, but I have yet to check if this is indeed the case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using Charles Proxy.  This application is a swiss-army knife tool set for any application that uses HTTP communication.  You can adjust throttling speed (potentially long enough to trigger tour timeout) as well as mapping remote hosts to a local server (and vice-versa).  There are a ton of options and tools - and I find it very useful.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Cheers, looks like it could be useful. Is there anyway of using this in combination with a device (if the device is connected to a Mac)?

Comment: Here are the instructions for that: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/